# Running a flask website in a subdirectory with apache

Tags: python, apache, flask

I'm using apache on my personal server, and I'm trying to run a 'main' website made with `Silex` on `www.mydomain.com/` and another one made using `Flask` on `www.mydomain.com/something`

To run the `Flask` website I'm using mod_wsgi as explained on their official website (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/mod_wsgi/).

It works just fine, I can reach my website at `www.mydomain.com/something`, but when I go back to `www.mydomain.com/` I get a `Flask` 404 error message.

I've tried checking the `apache` doc about virtual hosts but I can't make sense of it, here is my current `'sites-enabled/defaults'` configuration file :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        WSGIDaemonProcess bc user=bc group=bc threads=5
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/bc/bc.wsgi
        <Directory /var/www/bc>
                   WSGIProcessGroup bc
                   WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                   Order deny,allow
                   Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

my `/var/www` directory looks like this :

```
./index.php

./bc/

./bc/index.py
```

How can I get the python website to only work in www.mydomain.com/something and let the PHP one run on www.mydomain.com/ ?

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558249/nginx-configuration-for-static-sites-in-root-directory-flask-apps-in-subdirecto ?

Comment: Just saw there is a comment about apache there... I'll try doing what it says, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The first parameter to `WSGIScriptAlias` is the [url path](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIScriptAlias), by specifying `WSGIScriptAlias / <foo>` you're telling apache to send all requests to the WSGI app. Try `WSGIScriptAlias /something <foo>`